# How to download and upload s3 objects in same bucket (different prefixes) with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm implementing an image processing algorithm with an AWS lambda function. I want to gather images from a 'subfolder'/prefix in an S3 bucket, run my algorithm with boto3, and upload the processed images to a different 'subfolder'/prefix in the same S3 bucket.

I have not yet been successful with moving the images around within the same S3 bucket or under prefixes. I am able to use a boto3 resource or client to download an image from the 'root' folder in the bucket and then upload the processed image to a different bucket. However, I have been unsuccessful in accessing an image that is in a 'subfolder'/prefix.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
    file_path = '/tmp/' + key

    s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, file_path)

    # call image processing algorithm here

    s3_client.upload_file(file_path, 'bucket/folder_a/folder_b', key)
```

The key that is being passed in with the event is `'folder_a/folder_b/IMG_X.jpg'`. I've been getting file not found errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting file not found errors because boto3 didn't like the way I was passing the key to the `download_file` function. Instead of passing the key with the entire folder structure (as the S3 console shows the key to be), I just passed the base file name.

For the `upload_file` function it is necessary to pass the entire folder structure (with the file name) of where you want the file to be stored in the S3 bucket.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for record in event['Records']:
        try:
            bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
            key = record['s3']['object']['key']
            file_name = key.split('/')[-1]
            file_path = '/tmp/' + file_name

            s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, file_path)

            # call image processing algorithm here

            s3_client.upload_file(file_path, <target bucket>, 'folder_a/folder_b' + file_name)

            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': 'Success'
            }
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info(e)
            return {
                'statusCode': 400,
                'body': 'Error'
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting the path as part of the bucket name. Add it instead to the beginning of the key like:

```
s3_client.upload_file(file_path, 'bucket', 'folder_a/folder_b' + key)
```

Comment: Separating out the folder structure from the bucket worked. It is necessary to pass the entire folder structure to dictate where you want the file to be stored in the S3 bucket. Thanks!